# Keyword-based documentation for CPython extensions

Tags: python, pydoc

How CPython extensions should be written in order for `pydoc` to mention the arguments'name instead of `(...)`?

I've followed the [official python tutorial about extending Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#keyword-parameters-for-extension-functions), and even for the `keywdarg.parrot` procedure I get:

```
$> pydoc kewdarg.parrot

parrot(...)
   Print a lovely skit to standard output.
```

whereas I would expect

```
parrot(voltage, state="a stiff", action="voom", type="Norwegian Blue")
   Print a lovely skit to standard output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [sources of pydoc](http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/Python-2.4.3/dev/Lib/pydoc.py), if I'm not mistaken the stanza that produces the '...' is:

```
if inspect.isfunction(object):
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(object)
    argspec = inspect.formatargspec(
        args, varargs, varkw, defaults, formatvalue=self.formatvalue)
    if realname == '<lambda>':
        title = '<strong>%s</strong> <em>lambda</em> ' % name
        argspec = argspec[1:-1] # remove parentheses
else:
    argspec = '(...)'
```

So, `inspect.isfunction(object)` is returning False in the case of CPython extensions.
Since inspect.isfunction() checks that the object is a *Python function*, while C extension functions are considered *builtins*, then the above will return False and we get `(...)` in the output.